# Failure to load ApplicationContext when running JUnit tests in Spring with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, junit, gradle

I'm currently working on providing tests to my Gradle project. I'm using IntelliJ14.0.2 and I try to run my tests as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BatchConfiguration.class,  TestConfiguration.class})
public class EventGameReaderTest {

    @Autowired
    EventGameReader eventGameReader;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Test
    public  void queryDatabaseForEventGamesReturnsArrayListOfEventGames() {
         // Doing some stuff in the database.
    }
}
```

I dont know if this is relevant or not, but the BatchConfiguration is located in src/main/java/. The EventGameReaderTest is located in src/test/java. Running the test gives me the following exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext. I'm assuming that somehow there is a classpath issue, but I don't see how or where I would fix it.

Any suggestions for a fix are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your configuration classes as well.

Comment: Does it work through the cli?  just trying to eliminate intellij

Comment: No it doesnt, it comes up with the IllegalStateException. Excuses for the late reply, i had the weekend off.